# Why did Saul miss Walden's memorial service at Langley to go to Nazir's burial at sea?

Tags: plot-explanation, homeland

I am really puzzled by this. Saul from [Homeland](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1796960/) missed the memorial service of the Vice President of the United States in order to attend a burial of a terrorist. Why would he do this?

Thanks to this, not only does he survive, but he also becomes the head of the CIA. It kind of makes me think back to the first season when he failed a lie detector test and then rushed from the room, as if he was hiding something.

Comment: He missed the memorial (not a funeral) for the VP to oversee the disposal of Nazir's body (again, not a funeral). That's not quite the same thing as you have stated. Basically...he was doing his job.

Comment: You're right on the corrections, but you got the point of my question regardless. So, this was appointed to him? It wasn't his preference?

Comment: That's my understanding....but I'd have to go back and watch it again.

Comment: I just watched the part in the last episode of season 2 when Saul talks to Carrie about this. Carrie: Well, you look nice. Saul: I'm overseeing Nazir's ceremony. Carrie: Mmm. Burial at sea? Saul: Seems to be the method of choice these days. Want to come along? Carrie: Oh, I promised Brody I'd see him at the memorial service.

Comment: I don't think we can really conclude from this whether it was his personal choice to go, or he was appointed by supervisors... :/

Comment: Oversee is a *function* to my way of thinking....rather than a preference. It sounds like a job.

Comment: Yeah it does sound binding, but the guy is dead, it's not like he is going to run away or something.. If it was a task, it is kinda ridiculous to send someone as important as Saul to conduct it...That's why I think that even if this task existed it wasn't ordered explicitly to Saul to go there. I think he went there by choice.

Comment: I don't think one gets to choose whether or not they attend such a function. The entire plot line with Nazir mirrored a lot of what happened with Osama bin Laden. I doubt anyone who attended bin Laden's burial at sea had a choice as to whether to be there or not. I would assume it's the same for Saul in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason Saul oversaw Nazir's funeral is simple: They did not want to kill off his character. Saul is well-loved, plus he's one of the good guys (notice how most of the characters who were killed off had done questionable things.) If you're asking from an agency perspective why he went, then they sent Saul along to see that it was done right. As Saul notes "it's the way they do it these days" is possibly a reference to Bin Laden's funeral, as he was also buried at sea. The reason for this is so that the body cannot be retrieved.

@Paulie_D To call Nazir's burial at sea a 'disposal of his body' is totally incorrect. They gave him a proper funeral. His body was washed, shrouded, and prayers were made in the fashion of a respectable Islamic funeral ceremony.